# Wordpress, redirect user after clicking delete post shortcut button

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am working on a new plugin. I am dealing with a problem that I have outlined in the title. My intention is to redirect the user to the My Pages page after the user clicks the "Delete page" button.

Here is my code:

```
function custom_admin_bar_delete_link( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    global $post;
    if( is_admin() || ! is_object( $post ) )
        return;
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'delete_pages' ) )
        return;
    if ( $post->post_type != 'page' )
        return;
    $args = array(
        'id'    => 'delete_link',
        'title' => 'Delete this page',
        'href'  => get_delete_post_link( $post->ID ),
        'meta'  => array( 'class' => 'delete-link' )
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'custom_admin_bar_delete_link', 999 );

function custom_page_delete_redirect( $location, $post_id ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( 'page' === $post->post_type && 'trash' === get_post_status( $post_id ) ) {
        return admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );
    }
    return $location;
}
add_filter( 'wp_redirect', 'custom_page_delete_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having? You don't mention this. Please add some details to clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

Without thinking too hard about it, I would add an ID to your button and just write some jQuery to do the redirect.
(The PHP: NOT tested)

**EDIT:**
Per the Wordpress documentation, you should be able to add an ID:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_admin_bar/add_node/

```
$args = array(
'id'    => 'delete_link',
'title' => 'Delete this page',
'href'  => get_delete_post_link( $post->ID ),
'id'  => "someid",
'meta'  => array( 'class' => 'delete-link' )
```

);

The jQuery:

**EDIT:**
How are you adding the jQuery?  You should probably save it in a separate file in your plugin folder (maybe in a subfolder named "js") and enqueue it in your plugin.  The 2nd answer to this question would be a good place to start:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42641/how-to-include-a-simple-jquery-file-into-a-wordpress-plugin

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('body').on('click','#someid',function(event){
        // window.alert('jquery executing');
        setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = "http://example.com/page/";}, 500);
    });
});
```

Thoughts:  I added a timeout, because Wordpress loads slowly sometimes, and I've had to do this for other applications in Wordpress, but try without and see if it performs without the timeout.

Comment: Please review the edits I made.  Are you familiar with inspecting the element in your browser?  In chrome, right click on the element, and select "inspect" at the bottom of the menu.  Make sure your ID is present.  The problem is probably that the jQuery isn't inserted correctly, and I've offered a good link with a code example to help.  Let me know if it's working.

Comment: hello, you are right i made a mistakes when im inserting js codes. can you do me a favor and write all the codes in php?

Comment: I found another Stack Overflow question similar to yours, and I think it will probably work as a pure PHP solution.  I'm adding it as another answer so that people in the future can have this answer without having to read all of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/132196/get-delete-post-link-redirect

The question is similar, and this may get you where you need to go.